# Reading a file to get 2d array in Java 8

Tags: java, arrays, file, java-8

I am trying to read a simple text file that looks like this:

```
operationName1 Value
operationName2 Value
```

The operation names are strings (there are only two possible operations) and the values are ints.

My goal is to have an array as the output that looks like this:

```
[[1,10],[2,5]]
```

In the specified array, I would transform the operationName1 into 1 and operationName2 into 2, with the corresponding value.

This is what I tried:

```
try{
    Path path = Paths.get("./myFile.txt");
    String[][] array = Files.lines(path)
                    .map(s -> s.split("\\s+", 2))
                    .map(a -> new String[]{a[0], a[1]})
                    .toArray(String[][]::new);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }catch(IOException e){  
}
```

I did not change the names to integer in this code, I simply started by trying to get an array of string that I can print to see if I am reading the file correctly.

My output looks like this:

```
[[Ljava.lang.String;@682a0b20, [Ljava.lang.String;@3d075dc0, [Ljava.lang.String;@214c265e, [Ljava.lang.String;@448139f0, [L ...
```

Am I only getting a stream instead of strings?

The path is correct, I can read the file normally using standard syntax. But I would really like to understand the *new* syntax to start on the right foot, as understanding it seems helpful.

**My question:** Would you have an idea on how can I correct this problem, or even better, an idea on how I could have my expected output using the most recent syntax? (Java 8 if possible?)

PS: I also saw this syntax but I am not sure how to complete it to get my result, and I am not sure if this would be better or worse (but it seems to be Java 8).

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("myFile.txt")
    .toURI())).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you really need is the following

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

Otherwise, you're printing each array. And knowing that when calling a print on an array, a sort of reference/hashcode is printed, you get the result from above.

`Arrays#deepToString` prevents that and prints each element from each array.

---

The following lines are basically doing the same thing. You should just keep the first one.

Since your lines only contains two values, you do not need the second line.

```
.map(s -> s.split("\\s+", 2))           returns a Stream<String[]>
.map(a -> new String[]{a[0], a[1]})     returns a Stream<String[]>
```

---

Another suggestion would be to use a `map` object if the values from column one are unique.

```
Map<String, Integer> map = Stream.of("1 10", "2 5")
                                 .map(x -> x.split(" "))
                                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> String.valueOf(a[0]), 
                                                           a -> Integer.parseInt(a[1])));
```

---

### Credit to @Tunaki

To avoid a ressources leak, use a `try-with-ressources` with `Files.lines`

```
String[][] array;
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
    array = lines.map(s -> s.split("\\s+", 2))
                 .toArray(String[][]::new);
}
```

Comment: I'd also point out that the `Stream` returned by `Files.lines` needs to be closed in a try-with-resources.

Comment: @Tunaki Thanks I'm hesitating. Is this good?

Comment: Yes, it's also mentioned in the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-): *If timely disposal of file system resources is required, the try-with-resources construct should be used to ensure that the stream's close method is invoked after the stream operations are completed.*